# how to read a dataframe as a matrix?

Tags: r, csv, matrix, numeric

I want to read the csv file as a matrix, and the matrix is numeric.
The followwing is my code

## 1, read the data

```
mydata<-read.csv("mydata.csv", header = TRUE, sep=',', check.names = FALSE)
str(mydata)
```

## 2, transform as numeric data

```
mydata_1<-data.matrix(mydata)
str(mydata_1)
```

For the first step, the output is fine[image: see pic1]

but for the second step, when I want to transform the dataframe as a numeric matrix, the output is changed to be as follows. See that the rownames and the column names have been changed, and the cell values are also not true, which are not wanted.
[image: see pic2]

I also tried the following syntax, but it produced the same result as above.

```
mydata_1<-sapply(mydata, as.numeric)
```

and here is the link of my data file [link of mydata](https://www.dropbox.com/s/42ylqyn4d55hx8v/mydata.csv?dl=0)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: My guess (and I'm not going to download your data. You should make your question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) without a link to external data) is that your data were factors to begin with.

Comment: Have you tried `read.csv(...,na.strings = "--")`?

Comment: You might also try `row.names = 1` in your `read.csv()` call, to make that first column into the row names. And a side note: `header = TRUE` and `sep = ","` are the default values in `read.csv()`.  You don't need to write them.

Comment: Try this: `as.matrix(read.csv("mydata.csv", row.names = 1, check.names = FALSE))`

Comment: Thank you @Marat Talipov. combining you and Richard's suggestion, it perfectly work! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you @RichardScriven, it works by adding ' row.names = 1' and 'na.strings = "--" '. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have several data types (factor, num), and a matrix can only store one single data type. I'd suggest you remove the first column to have only numerics:

```
mydata_1<-data.matrix(mydata[,-1])
```

Comment: Thank you @HubertL , but I need the country names as the row names, so I can't remove it. This is the first problem, and the second problem is that the ` data.matrix() ` function will change the magnitude of data value, which is not wanted.

Comment: why do you want to use matrix?

Comment: Thank you @HubertL. You are right. The problem truely lies in the rownames, so by adding 'rowname= 1', the problem is solved.